# What is the Imperial Guard's Cap?

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war

In Dawn of War I, Dark Crusade how many vehicles can the Imperial Guard field at Tier 3? I can increase the cap by building Mechanized Command buildings, but no matter how many of these buildings I build the vehicle cap never goes past **20**.

**Is the Imperial Guard's maximum vehicle cap 20? Is there a way to increase it further? What is their Tier 3 Infantry Cap?**

Answer (score 2):

The max cap is only 20 like any other.